# Inputting mean yearly values with sporadic dates into organized datetime data frame

Tags: python, datetime

New to everything, apologies in advance.
I have csv of data with values from separate sources.  The values were measured on a variety of dates and frequencies depending on the source.  It looks like this:

```
Source,Date,Value
a,2/11/1992,18  
a,2/28/1992,16  
a,3/1/1993,15  
a,4/2/1995,2  
b,1/1/1990,1  
b,1/13/1990,3  
b,5/5/1993,4  
b,6/3/1995,5  
c,1/13/1990,3  
c,1/1/1991,3  
c,1/2/1992,1
```

This is just a sample, there is a lot of values and sources.

I would like to create a dataframe that is composed of mean values for each source over the a year.  It would look something like this:

```
Source,1990,1991,1992,1993,1994,1995  
a,NaN,NaN,17,15,NaN,2  
b,2,NaN,Nan,4,NaN,5  
c,3,3,1,NaN,NaN,NaN
```

I am able to apply a pivot to a single source and get the desired result, but because the values were not measured at the date/frequency, I cannot apply pivot multiple sources.

Comment: Convert the column to datetime, then use [resample](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html) and pivot the result

Comment: Thanks G. Anderson.  I tried that and it did resample, but it did not do so by the Source (code below).  Do you have a suggestion for how I can resample values based on their source?  Thanks   df.resample('Y', on ='DateEdit').mean()